# How to pass views in ViewPager without pass for all views

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager, fragment

I've got a ViewPager with my own adapter that extends of FragmentPagerAdapter, well everything works fine, but when I pass from the first view in position 0 to other view, for example in position 5, my application passes by all the views to stay in view 5.

I would like to found some way to change this, and when I pass from the first view to other, my application makes it without pass for other views.

I use this method to go to some view that have added previously in my adapter:

myViewPager.setCurrentItem(int position); //To go to position of the list;

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation, you will see that you can pass a second parameter to `setCurrentItem()` to enable or disable the scrolling.

"True to smoothly scroll to the new item, false to transition immediately"

E.g.

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(5, false);
```

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int,%20boolean)